# Which tense is correct: Was or Were

Tags: tenses

Which is correct?

I wish everything was as easy
OR
I wish everything were as easy

Comment: In writing and formal speech, *wish* takes the past subjunctive.

Answer (score -1):

"Everything" is singular, so you should use the singular form "was".

*I wish everything was as easy.*

Comment: One can only wish it were so.

Answer (score -1):

**Everything** is treated as a singular noun. In fact, any noun phrase that contains **every** is singular.

> Every student **has** three books.
>
> On a cruise, every day **is** filled with fun.

Comment: This is irrelevant: *wish* takes a past tense, usually past subjunctive.